# OS - Parallel between heap/stack and pages

Tags: operating-systems, virtual-memory, paging

I'm studying for an exam on Operating Systems. I am working on the chapter concerning **virtual memory**.

I'm getting really confused making a parallel between [this very common schema](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/images/Chapter9/9_02_VirtualAddressSpace.jpg) describing a process, and the [pages that are allocated in virtual memory](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/images/Chapter9/9_01_VirtualMemoryLarger.jpg).

Are these pages allocated to store the entire process ? Are the pages actually free space for the heap ? Or the stack ?

I really cannot link those two concepts

Comment: Each individual process may have one or more virtual pages ...

Comment: So does that mean that pages in virtual memory are only allocated for the data used by the process ?

Comment: No. The OS puts whatever it wants in virtual memory. That can include program code as well as data.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory. It covers paged virtual memory :)